# getElementByTagName not working

Tags: javascript

When I click delete button without clicking any checkbox, it should show alert, but in this coding, if first checkbox checked, it doesn't show alert. If second checkbox checked, it show alert.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="checkbox">
       <input type="CHECKBOX" name="MyCheckbox" class="checkbox"  value="This..." >
       <input type="CHECKBOX" name="MyCheckbox" class="checkbox"  value="This..." >
       <input type="CHECKBOX" name="MyCheckbox" class="checkbox"  value="This..." >
       <input type="CHECKBOX" name="MyCheckbox" class="checkbox"  value="This..." >
   </div>
        <form action="DeleteServer" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Delete!">
        </form>
```

**script function:**

```
function checkCheckBoxes() {
    var chk = document.getElementById("checkbox").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<chk.length;i++){
       if (document.getElementById("checkbox").getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked == false) 
       {
           alert ('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!');
           return false;
       } else {    
           return true;
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked` or `getElementsByTagName("input")[1].checked` should help.

Comment: Its working. But i want to add several checkbox means, how to write for loop before condition

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify where's the problem.

Comment: @Mohaideen you mean a for loop to check which `checkboxes` are checked?

Comment: No. find number of checkboxes there. I have edited my question. check above

Comment: I have confusion in condition, see the question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
var inputs     = document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox input');
    is_checked = false;

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].name == 'MyCheckbox') {
        is_checked = inputs[i].checked;
        if(is_checked) break;
    }
}

if(!is_checked){
  alert('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!');
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCrnn/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` has an **s** in it. It is plural. It returns a NodeList not a single Element.

Given your HTML, that NodeList will include 2 separate `input`s.

You have to loop over it (as if it was an Array) and test the `checked` property of *each* `input` in turn.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol — That was edited into the question after I wrote this, and probably in response to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCheckBoxes() {
      var inputs     = document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox input');
      is_checked = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                is_checked = inputs[i].checked;
                if(is_checked) return true;
            }
        }

        if(!is_checked){
          alert('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!');
          return false;
        }
    }
```